Gitlab Pipeline - Read output json from the previous job
Below is my gitlab-ci.yml file, where I have 2 stages.
stages:
  - upload
  - publish

upload-file:
  stage: upload
  script:
    - <command>
  when: manual

publish-file:
  stage: publish
  script:
    - command --fileId=1234    # Need to read fileId from the upload-file job output
  needs: [upload-theme]
  when: manual

When the first job 'upload-file' is successful, it outputs below json
{
  "fileId": "ef595c63-b5cb-453d-8f3a-8ad2697a0526"
}

I need to access this fileId in my second job -> 'publish-file'.
How can I achieve this? Please advise.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_artifacts.html

I tried adding artifacts as suggested,
upload-file:
stage: upload
script:
- 
artifacts:
paths:
- file.txt
publish-file:
stage: publish
script:
- cat file.txt
Getting below error.
Uploading artifacts...
WARNING: file.txt: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory (/builds/org/web/app-files)
ERROR: No files to upload. Please help.

Which path are you writting the file.txt to? it needs to be relative to the project dir. Paths are relative to the project directory ($CI_PROJECT_DIR) and can’t directly link outside it.
